# Is it true that the set $\{x\colon \partial\phi(x)\subset B_r(0)\}$ is convex when $\phi$ is convex?

Tags: convex-analysis

Let $\phi\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ be convex. Is it true that the sets
$$
A_r = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n\;\colon\; \partial \phi(x) \subset B_r(0)\},\quad r>0,
$$
are convex?

For $n=1$ this follows from monotonicity. Indeed, for any pair of points such that $x_0<x_1$ and any intermediate point $x_t=(1-t)x_0+tx_1$, $t\in [0,1]$, it follows that
$$
p_{x_0}\leq p_{x_t}\leq p_{x_1}\quad \forall p_{x_0}\in \partial\phi(x_0),\quad \forall p_{x_1}\in \partial\phi(x_1),\quad \forall p_{x_t}\in \partial\phi(x_t).
$$
Hence,
$$
-r \le \min\{\partial\phi(x_0)\}\le p_{x_t} \le \max\{\partial\phi(x_1)\}\le r.
$$
But what about $n\ge 2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. Indeed, consider the case when $n=2$ and
$$f(x,y)=\max(| x|,2 | y|)$$
for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$.

Then for $(x,y)$ near $(\pm1,0)$ we have $f(x,y)=|x|$ and hence $\partial f(\pm1,0)\subseteq B_1(0)$. On the other hand, $f(0,y)=2|y|$, so that $\partial f(0,0)\not\subseteq B_1(0)$.

Comment: Thanks! There's something I still don't understand. If $f$ is taken as $\sup$ of all affine functions lying below the triangular strip, then it should be $+\infty$ for $y\in (-\infty,-h)\cup (h,+\infty)$. How can it be extended?

Comment: @user522653 : The maximum is to be taken only over the rectangle $R$, and then the resulting function is to be extended.

Comment: The counterexample is now greatly simplified (and the description of the tortuous way it was found is removed).

Comment: That's a great example. Thank you!